Can you identify this component that is written C AA89 7.372M on it?
I have learned about https://smd.yooneed.one/ but it wasn't helpful on this component (or is it?) The component is marked Y, so I guess that it is a crystal oscillator. Can you help me identify this component?


the 7.372M is a giveaway that it is some form of resonator / oscillator with 7.372 MHz.

It's going to be one of four things, a crystal, a resonator, a filter, or an oscillator. The frequency is 7.372 MHz, the other markings could be a batch code or date code.
If it had just two contacts it would be a crystal or resonator but it appears to have more than two, so it could still be one of those, or it could be an oscillator or filter. A Filter would tend to be labeled FL rather than Y, so we can probably rule that out. If there is power and ground going to two of the connections it would be an oscillator, if it just has connections to something like the clock pins of a MCU then it's a crystal or resonator.

Thank you for your kind answer. It has 4 pins and one of them is connected to the OSC2/CLKO/RC15 pin of a dsPIC30F3014. I had the notion that the marking on a component ALWAYS indicates what exact component it is written on. I was mistaken obviously. I will give more information if I were to ask an identification question again.

@KeremAkinli Without knowing the manufacturer it's hard to tell what a marking like that would mean. It might indicate a specific component, but without a reference such as a datasheet there's generally not much to go on.
